# Method queryInventoryAsync In-app Billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm trying to use billing in my application. I read the official documentation, but some things do not work for me.

I need to get the cost of purchases by id. But my code does not compile:

**MainActivity**

```
import com.developer.skyline.livewallpapershd.util.IabHelper;
import com.developer.skyline.livewallpapershd.util.IabResult;
import com.developer.skyline.livewallpapershd.util.Inventory;
...

private IabHelper mHelper;
...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String base64EncodedPublicKey = "My Public Key";

        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                    try {
                        ArrayList<String> additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        additionalSkuList.add("all");
                        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, mGotInventoryListener);
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
            }
        });
    }

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Query Inventory Error!");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Query Inventory Success!");
                // update UI accordingly
            }
        }
    };
```

My problem is related to this method **queryInventoryAsync()**

*Cannot resolve method queryInventoryAsync*

https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=af1b85c0c86aa0663130d8ab2fe853f2

I saw similar questions, but I did not find a solution for myself.

**Log**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
D:\AndroidStudio\AndroidStudioProjects\LiveWallpapersHD\app\src\main\java\com\developer\skyline\livewallpapershd\MainActivity.java
Error:(62, 32) error: no suitable method found for queryInventoryAsync(boolean,ArrayList<String>,QueryInventoryFinishedListener)
method IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(boolean,List<String>,List<String>,QueryInventoryFinishedListener) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(QueryInventoryFinishedListener) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.838 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the method `queryInventoryAsync()` holds one or four paramters. If you look into the source code see the following desciption:

```
   /**
     * Asynchronous wrapper for inventory query. This will perform an inventory
     * query as described in {@link #queryInventory}, but will do so asynchronously
     * and call back the specified listener upon completion. This method is safe to
     * call from a UI thread.
     *
     * @param querySkuDetails as in {@link #queryInventory}
     * @param moreItemSkus as in {@link #queryInventory}
     * @param moreSubsSkus as in {@link #queryInventory}
     * @param listener The listener to notify when the refresh operation completes.
     */

public void queryInventoryAsync(final boolean querySkuDetails, final List<String> moreItemSkus,
            final List<String> moreSubsSkus, final QueryInventoryFinishedListener listener)
throws IabAsyncInProgressException.....
```

and for the single paramter, there is no description (it´s declared in the one above):

```
 public void queryInventoryAsync(QueryInventoryFinishedListener listener)
        throws IabAsyncInProgressException{
        queryInventoryAsync(false, null, null, listener);
}
```

The documentation of InApp Billing and the `IABHelper` class is absolutely poor, but I guess it´s enough to call only `queryInventoryAsync(QueryInventoryFinishedListener listener)` and you will get all informations inside the listener.

The listener returns `IabResult result` and `Inventory inv` . These hold all information you need.

IABHelper on GitHub:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java

Answer (score 1):

The method you are calling has the signature:

`queryInventoryAsync(boolean,List<String>,List<String>,QueryInventoryFinishedListener)`

(4 parameters)

You are calling it with only 3 parameters.

If you check the sample code on [Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java), you will see that there is no method with only 3 parameters.

Comment: Thanks but I don't need the docs. I was just telling you what was wrong with your code. (The error message you posted is stating the expected parameters)   IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(boolean, List<String>, List<String>, QueryInventoryFinishedListener) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: @user233804 - The docs are not really helpful. They are outdated, you can´t count on them. I don´t know why Google provides such patchy information, but it is like it is. We must come to terms with it ourselves. Check out the GitHub Project for IABHelper. You definetely need all four parameters or just one like I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me